# windows azure development storage blob service not starting

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-storage-emulator

When I start development storage emulator, I get an error

`The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process`

I guess this is happening only for BLOB, other services i.e. Queue and Tables start successfully

What could be the problem? I am using Azure SDK v1.4

[image: Development Storage Emulator start error]

Comment: What version of the Azure SDK are you using?  I seem to recall that this was a confirmed bug that was fixed.

Comment: For anyone recently experiencing this issue, I found that I got this after I installed HDInsight, the Azure Hadoop feature http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/services/hdinsight/.

Java listens on ports that conflict with the Azure Storage emulator.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Stop BitTorrent. In my experience, this error is usually a port conflict, and BitTorrent does typically grab port 10000. If it's not BitTorrent, look for other apps that might be holding on to port 10000. Netstat can probably help.

Comment: Thanks for the idea!!! For me the conflict is with Cerberus FTP Server (the soap interface)!

Answer (score 17):

This might be another process using the port that Azure dev storage is using.

To figure out which app is that, run `netstat` first:

```
netstat -p tcp -ano | findstr :10000
```

You will get a process id (PID) in the last column:

```
  TCP    0.0.0.0:10000          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       2204
```

It means that process listening to this port is ID 2204. Then run `taklist`:

```
tasklist /fi "pid eq 2204"
```

So you will see something like this:

```
Image Name                     PID Session Name        Session#    Mem Usage
========================= ======== ================ =========== ============
SMSvcHost.exe                 2204 Services                   0     29 300 K
```

So now you know that `SMSvcHost.exe` is listening on that port.

If you can't stop the process using the port, there's a way to remap the ports used by DevFabric. The solution is taken from [this blog post](http://mohamadhalabi.com/2011/06/03/azure-storage-emulator-process-cannot-access-the-file-because-it-is-being-used-by-another-process/):

> You could do that by navigating to C:\Program Files\Windows Azure
>   SDK\v1.4\bin\devstore (replace 1.4 with your SDK version) and opening
>   **DSService.exe.config**. From there you could change the configuration
>   and make your services listen to other ports.

For me in **v1.6** the path was `C:\Program Files\Windows Azure Emulator\emulator\devstore\DSService.exe.config`

For **SDK v2.5 / Storage v3.4** the path is `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\WAStorageEmulator.exe.config`

For **Emulator v4+** the path is `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\AzureStorageEmulator.exe.config`

But be careful, because you will not be able to use `UseDevelopmentStorage=true` in your connection string anymore (e.g. connect with Azure Storage Explorer).

- `DsInit` doesn't help
- Specifying the connection string this way https://stackoverflow.com/a/7037036/182371 doesn't help either.

In order to connect, use a custom connection string that is targeting the new endpoint ports you defined.  You'll still want to connect using the [standard, well-known storage emulator account name and key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh403989.aspx).  An example connection string can be [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24365307/azure-emulator-port-conflict-app-tries-to-connect-to-wrong-port/24365699#24365699).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, but in my case, the problem was somewhere else. There was the **process *System* (PID 4) listening on the port 10,000**, so it's obvious I wasn't able to kill such process. The only workaround was to reboot Windows (Windows 7 64-bit), but that's too extreme and time consuming.

The most challenging part was to identify, why is the *System* process listening on that port. Google didn't help at all in this case.

So I simply tried to connect to the port 10,000 on *localhost* using *Netcat* (better Telnet) and send there something:

```
$ nc 127.0.0.1 10000
```

I quickly noticed from the response, that there is an HTTP server listening on the port 10,000. The most important information in the response was this header:

```
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
```

Then it was really fast to free this port for Azure Emulator. Brief googling revealed the details about *what* is this thing actually doing:
[HTTP Server API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364510(v=vs.85).aspx), and most importantly *who* is it doing: [Windows HTTP Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384273(v=vs.85).aspx).

Then I went to *Services Management Console*, found the service called **Service WinHTTP WPAD** which was running and simply **stopped it**. And voila, the port 10,000 is free as a bird now.

---

Does anyone know how does it work? I guess that some 3rd application creates a listening HTTP server on the port 10,000 using the *WinHTTP WPAD* service. I doubt that it's anything from Microsoft since they wouldn't configure the Azure Emulator to use the port already used by them.

Answer (score 1):

this error really bothered me and finally I have figured out how to fix it.

Yes, the error is caused by port conflict, the port 10000 is used by another process, in my case, it is a process called "azurite"... not sure what it, but sounds like something relate to azure :)

Anyways, this command to identify the PID of the process that uses 10000

```
netstat -p tcp -ano | findstr :10000
```

The last number '132864' is the pid

[image]

run

```
tasklist /fi "pid eq 132864"
```

to see the name of the process.

Finally kill it by

```
taskkill /pid 132864 /f
```

and then I can successfully run the emulator

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there was no bit Torrent on my system. However, the port 1000 was being used by some java.exe. I figured out that running HDInsight locally doesn't work with Azure blob storage. So I went to Azure Storage Emulater UI and unchecked the blob. After that this issue got resolved.