# How do I configure an Azure role to connect to Windows Azure Storage Emulator using custom ports?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, azure, azure-storage

I needed to [customize my storage emulator ports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24365307/azure-emulator-port-conflict-app-tries-to-connect-to-wrong-port) to deal with a system process that uses the same default ports.  That all works fine.

Now, how do I update my Azure service role's configuration to use the updated ports?

Comment: Please explain what should be VS2010 projects would be looking for?

Comment: The project should point to the proper port number.  If you leave the settings to point to UseDevelopmentStorage=True; it will continue to try the default port numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but would something like this work? From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee758697.aspx:

```
BlobEndpoint=myBlobEndpoint;QueueEndpoint=myQueueEndpoint;TableEndpoint=myTableEndpoint;AccountName=myAccountName;AccountKey=myAccountKey
```

Comment: For local emulator it will be something like this (ports are non-standard):
`BlobEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10100;QueueEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10101;TableEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10102;AccountName=devstoreaccount1;AccountKey=Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==`

The most important part is the Account key/name, these are the default local emulator account credentials

Comment: These default local emulator credentials can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh403989.aspx (for anyone who, like me, was wondering where the magic credentials came from :)