# Azure Emulator Port conflict, app tries to connect to wrong port

Tags: azure, emulation, azure-storage

When starting the Azure Storage Emulator, it fails because of a port conflict with some dell drivers/software.

I solved this by changing urls in the `StorageEmulatorConfig` section inside `WAStorageEmulator.exe.config`.

```
<StorageEmulatorConfig>
    <services>
      <service name="Blob" url="http://127.0.0.1:10100/"/>
      <service name="Queue" url="http://127.0.0.1:10101/"/>
      <service name="Table" url="http://127.0.0.1:10102/"/>
    </services>

    <accounts.../>
  </StorageEmulatorConfig>
```

So now the emulator runs without problem.

My web application still tries to connect to the old ports, though....

The connection string that I use is the short one:

```
<add name="AzureStorage" connectionString="UseDevelopmentStorage=true;"/>
```

I have tried the normal form too:

```
<add name="AzureStorage" 
     connectionString="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;
                       AccountName=devstoreaccount1;
                       AccountKey=Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==;"/>
```

How does my app discover what endpoints it should use?
How can I tell it to use another port?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try by specifying endpoints in your connection string:

```
DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;
AccountName=devstoreaccount1;AccountKey=Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==;
BlobEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10100/devstoreaccount1;
QueueEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10101/devstoreaccount1;
TableEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10102/devstoreaccount1;
```

Comment: great! But it would be even greater to know how (or in this case, why not) the application discovers the right ports in the first place...

Comment: These default local emulator credentials can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh403989.aspx (for anyone who, like me, was wondering where the magic credentials came from :)

Comment: Adding @mcw0933 edit - Make sure there is no whitespace in the connection string, or you'll get a "No valid combination of account information found" error.

Comment: @mcw0933's link has moved https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-use-emulator/