# not able to connect azure storage emulator

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-storage-emulator

I followed below link:
[Azure Emulator Port conflict, app tries to connect to wrong port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24365307/azure-emulator-port-conflict-app-tries-to-connect-to-wrong-port/24365699#24365699)

But still getting this error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
HResult=-2146233079
Message=The account credentials for 'devstoreaccount1' are incorrect.
Source=Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host
```

my connection string is: `"UseDevelopmentStorage=true;DevelopmentStorageProxyUri=http://127.0.0.1;"`

using azure sdk beta 2.0.0 pre version

Comment: Do you suspect that there is a port conflict like in the question you linked to? Your connection string is using the default ports so if you've changed them you'll need to change your connection string too.

Comment: yes. I checked by changing connection string too. but still getting same error.

Comment: Can you run "AzureStorageEmulator.exe status" and also show your new connection string? Another debugging step would be to check the traffic in fiddler to see if the requests are being received by the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the latest [Azure SDK](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/).
Verify whether you followed the steps correctly during the installation of [local storage emulator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-emulator)

For you to make sure this works.

> You could see the **(Development)** under "Storage Accounts" in the
>   Storage Explorer resources tree after you've installed and started the
>   storage emulator.

It would be like

[image]