# Azure Emulator not running

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013, azure-emulator

I was debugging a cloud service and was using azure storage and compute emulator. Suddenly I noticed I began receiving `SEHException` when accessing a cloud table, and the emulator icon is not there anymore in the notification area.

I remember I checked `don't show this window again` sort of option, so that the annoying window of loading the emulator is not displayed.

I restarted my computer and ran VS2013 as admin with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh403989.aspx

You just need to go to **start** -> search: **Windows Azure Storage Emulator**

This will run the storage emulator only, but you can run the compute emulator through the notification area icon which displays when you start the storage emulator.

Edit:

The above mentioned solution did not actually solve my problem, I found later that I have to set the cloud service as the startup project, not the web role.

Edit 2:

It can be also because of running a BitTorrent client. [windows azure development storage blob service not starting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6415284/1151151)

Comment: @EF0 Glad to hear that :)